# Redmi note 8 - black screen won't turn on

Tags: screen, redmi

I bought a cheap and broken Redmi note 8, the previous owner told me it won't charge. When I got it in my hands I tried turning it on and it vibrates, turn the led on for a second but no image. (this looked weird as usually phones shows a dead battery logo or something in the screen)

I left it charging for a while to see if something happens. The led light turned on as if it was charging so now I doubt it is a charging board issue.

I saw some videos of a trick of factory reset pressing volume up and down and power buttons for 12 seconds, others mention different combination of buttons but neither of them seemed to work. The phone vibrates a few random times, I can't tell if it's turning on or anything.

Now I think it's either the screen or some problem in the logic board. What do you think? Am I missing something? Is there any way to diagnose either of these things without buying a screen replacement?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: connect to linux PC and check which mode is detected with `lsusb` from terminal. regardless display is broken you should still be able to enter fastboot mode. if display is working the phone might be in diagnostic or emergency download mode. if you are talking about Pro model SP Flash Tool might detect preloader mode

Answer (score 1):

You can clean battery connector point. Try another battery.

Check display connection.

Connect mobile to computer use USB cable for 20 minutes.
Disconnect mobile and again connect computer. If you see battery icon. then mobile is charging.

Use power and volume button to start mobile in recovery mode. Then select safe mode.